# Dynamic search filter in Rails/Grape to show blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape

In my app after pressing the filter button a search field appears - searching companies by company name. Everything works well but I'm just wondering how to implement scenario where user enters company name which doesn't exists in db and in the response gets blank page instead of list of all companies which is right now. Can I handle this through the backend side?

```
get do
  collection = Process.all.order(id: :asc) if params[:sort].blank?

  if params[:filters]
    contains = Process
               .where(
                 'company_name LIKE ?', "#{params[:filters][:company_name].downcase}%"
               )
  end

  scoped_collection = if contains.present?
                        scope_admin_resource(contains)
                      else
                        scope_admin_resource(collection)
                      end
  admin_serialize paginate(filter(sort(scoped_collection))) # this comes from some gem, it's not important
end
```